# Can't convert tiff image to a bitmap (matrix)

Tags: c#, uwp, bitmap, tiff

The function `GetBitMapColorMatrix` is ‏supposed to decode the tiff image and return a bitmap that describes the tiff image but for some reason, I get this exception -> `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'System.Drawing is not supported on this platform'`. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public Color[][] GetBitMapColorMatrix(string bitmapFilePath)
    {
        Bitmap b1 = new Bitmap(bitmapFilePath);

        int hight = b1.Height;
        int width = b1.Width;

        Color[][] colorMatrix = new Color[width][];
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            colorMatrix[i] = new Color[hight];
            for (int j = 0; j < hight; j++)
            {
                colorMatrix[i][j] = b1.GetPixel(i, j);
            }
        }
        return colorMatrix;
    }
```

Comment: That's seems to be the case in UWP See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/16112/uwp-app-for-xbox-systemdrawing-is-not-supported-on.html

Comment: so you are basically saying uwp doesnt  support bitmap

Comment: I am not an expert in UWP, so you can't take my word for granted. But searching for the exact error message gave me back that result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UWP does not use the full .net framework so the classes in System.Drawing are not available.   Their are some classes like [BitmapPallette](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmappalette?view=net-5.0) and [BitmapImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage?view=net-5.0) in the System.Media.Imaging namespace that could be useful.   I would also look at [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D) or [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/).

Comment: Pro tip: "Pallet" ≠ "Palette" ;)

Comment: Those two BitmapClasses are actually for the .NET versions, not UWP versions. Regardless for this case his two options are either as you suggested, Win2D's CanvasBitmap, or the built in SoftwareBitmap class.

Comment: can you show me how to decode an image using sharpDX?